# Building Angstrom following wiki: where is the image

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Angstrom, I first tried option 1. I have Angstrom with kernel 2.6.32, but I followed the instructions which left me with a ruined BeagleBoard-xM system. Several other "users" had been created, I could no longer log in as user, only as root and ROS was not installed. After flashing the kernel again and running git, I checked using "opkg list" for ROS packages and none were available. So I guess the recommendation should be "only with latest kernel". Then I build an image, but after building it I can't find the image. What is it called, where is it? Then I used bitbake for cross-compiling ROS. When that finished, I checked for ROS packages and found none. Where should I find them ?

Edit: I tried to create the image again and this time it even goes wrong before the image is finalized giving this error:

NOTE: Error during finalise of /home//devel/setup-scripts/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-lsb-sdk.bb
ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home//devel/setup-scripts/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-lsb-sdk.bb: Failure expanding variable toolchain_create_sdk_version: ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable METADATA_REVISION, expression was ${@base_detect_revision(d)} which triggered exception OSError: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
NOTE: Error during finalise of /home//devel/setup-scripts/sources/openembedded-core/meta/recipes-extended/images/core-image-lsb-dev.bb
ERROR: Command execution failed: Exited with 1

Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.

I guess I'm doing something wrong, but no clue what....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/86861/building-angstrom-following-wiki:-where-is-the-image.../) by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The problem is the combination of Angstrom and ROS. When I install Ubuntu I can install ROS groovy (and hydro) without a problem. The problem is that I want DSP as well, which is actively supported by Angstrom only.

Maybe I wasn't clear enough about this, but my latest attempts were building the image following http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Angstrom, options 1 and 2, so I did follow http://www.angstrom-distribution.org/building-angstrom. The first time it seemed to go fine, just couldn't find where the image was. The second time, the building ends in the reported errors.

Will be followed up...

---

Originally posted by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) with karma: 72 on 2013-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0